# Did John Ritter ever injure himself during filming Three's Company?

Tags: production, threes-company

I've always wondered if John Ritter (as Jack Tripper) had ever hurt himself during filming of Three's Company. There's alot of physical comedy, and I wonder if he ever received an injury from it. There is nothing online about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there's no concrete evidence to confirm or debunk this question, it's probable he never sustained any *serious* injury based on some information obtained online.

According to [this list of on-set injuries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_accidents), there is no entry for John Ritter prior to his death while filming an episode of "8 Simple Rules".

According to the [Three's Company episode guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Three's_Company_episodes), there was never any extreme gap in air dates that would indicate a lengthy hospital stay or recovery from broken bones.

So, while it's probable he sustained bumps and/or bruises doing some of his comedy scenes, it doesn't appear that it was anything more than that.

Comment: That's what i figured. I have the episode guide, and the show's bio, so i figured it would mentioned in those if something happened.

Comment: Not disputing the answer, but to my knowledge, episodes of a TV show are rarely being filmed *while that season is airing.*  They don't film each episode during the week and then throw it up at the last minute (South Park is a notable exception to this rule, from what I've heard.)  So, a primary actor sustaining a major injury would not likely result in a gap in air dates mid-season.  An injury sustained while filming might result in some last-minute script changes and delays while filming, but the episodes would still almost certainly be ready by the time the season starts airing.

Comment: also, if the actor gets seriously injured they would probably write the actor out of a few episodes or write the episodes to explain why they're not around so much, or they could work an injury into the script.